# Does some Java specification require `resources` content to be copied into `target`?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, maven-resources-plugin

Or is it just my IntelliJ IDEA's voluntary behavior? I have 8 files, each   3.5 GiB in size and IDEA copies them from `src/main/resources` into `target/classes/resources` during the `make` task. Is it possible to avoid such a  behaviour?

Comment: If you don't want the resources to be copied, why do you have them there at all? And no, the Java specification doesn't give any details about the build procedure, really.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The resources directory is for files that get built into the .jar output.

For large files, you should probably store them outside the resources directory and outside the .jar file.

Comment: It's that I'm currently running some performance tests about some particular subject and haven't chosen any directory structure yet, so I'm using quick-and-dirty variants as for now.